# Function whose integral is equal to the integral of a another function multiplied by the function itself

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

Suppose we have a continuous function $f$ where $$\int_{a}^b f(x)dx = \int_{a}^b e^xf(x)dx,$$ for some $a$ and $b.$ Then what can we say about $f?$ Can we determine $f$ or what type of peopertise does it have?

Comment: @Dole if $b=-a$ and $f(x)=x/(e^x-1)$...?

Comment: This is for all $a, b$ or for some $a, b?$

Comment: @IgorRivin: for some a ,b.

Answer (score 2):

The given identity is equivalent to $\int_a^b (e^x-1)f(x)\,dx = 0$. For most intervals $[a,b]$ we have $\int_a^b (e^x-1)\,dx \ne 0$; for such intervals, one can start with *any* integrable function $f(x)$ and modify it by a constant $f(x)+C$ to make $\int_a^b (e^x-1)(f(x)+C)\,dx = 0$. I would conclude that there's nothing particularly special about such functions $f(x)$.

Comment: The constant C is a functional of f, I don't know if the result $f+C[f]$, where $C[f]=-\frac{\int_a^b(e^x-1)f(x)dx}{\int_a^b(e^x-1)dx}$ is onto the relevant function set ?

Comment: It's obvious that the first function f cannot be a multiple of $e^x-1$

Answer (score 1):

We could notice : $<f|g>=\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx$, as it is a scalar product, then we seek f such that : $<f|e^x-1>=0$. To this end we could take any continuous integrable function g not multiple of $e^x-1$ and do Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation :
$$y(x)=g(x)-\frac{<g|e^x-1>}{<e^x-1|e^x-1>}(e^x-1)$$

It is simple to verify that y is then orthogonal to $e^x-1$ in the sense of the integral given.

This should work in the cases where $\int_a^be^x-1dx=0$ but $\int_a^b (e^x-1)^2dx\neq 0$

Comment: That's an interesting point of view (+1)